# Understanding the share() RxJS operator in action together with Rx.Observable.ajax

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to understand the behavior of the **RxJS 5** `share()` operator.

According to tutorials and documentation, `share()` turns a cold observable into a hot one.

I am trying to see that in action. Here is what I have tried:

```
const search$ = Rx.Observable.ajax('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=javascript').share();
```

And then the first time I subscribe to it:

```
search$.subscribe(console.log);
```

I see from the dev tools that a network request is issued:

```
 Request URL:https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=javascript
```

then upon rerunning the same subscription:

```
search$.subscribe(console.log);
```

I notice that **another network request is also issued**.

Can someone please explain why the `share()` operator is displaying this behavior? I was expecting just one network request to be issued...

**P.S.** using `xxx.publishLast().refCount();` instead of `xxx.share();` does the job but my main concern is to understand the `share()` behavior in the above context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`share` is a shortcut for `publish().refCount()`. The `refCount`-part means, that the stream is hot/shared as long as there is at least 1 subscriber - howver, it is being reset/cold when there are no subscribers. When your `ajax`-requests finishes, the stream completes and upon completion of a stream any subscriber is automatically being unsubscribed -> setting the subribers of the stream to 0 and therefor resetting the stream - which is why you are experiencing a second network-quest on any future subscription.

Why does this work with `publishLast().refCount()`? - with `publishLast()` you get a stream that never completes, therefor no subscriber is automatically unsubscribed and the stream is never being reset.

---

For caching HTTP-Responses your approach with `publishLast().refCount()` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks olsn. This makes the exhibited behavior clearer now. Just one more interrogation I have: is `publishLast().refCount()` and the implied never-completing stream deemed a good practice in order to cache http requests?

Comment: Yes absolutely - but i've updated the answer with an additional link to the rxjs-doc-section here on SO

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailled reply and the link!